# Does python static method consume less memory than instance method

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, memory-management, static-methods

I have several instance methods that use `self` within them, but only in a couple places.

I can pass the objects to these methods directly and make them `staticmethod`s. Does that consume less memory?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are micro-optimising here for no benefit.

Yes, a regular method involves a new `method` object that is created to handle the binding between function and instance, but that's only a bit of memory (2 pointers plus some Python metadata) *used only during the duration of the call or if you stored the bound method* <sup>*</sup>. A `staticmethod` object doesn't create a new method object, but that's offset by the *about the same amount of memory needed for the `staticmethod` object*:

```
>>> import sys
>>> class Foo:
...     def bar(self): pass
...     @staticmethod
...     def staticbar(): pass
...
>>> sys.getsizeof(Foo().bar)   # bound method object size
64
>>> sys.getsizeof(Foo.__dict__['staticbar'])  # staticmethod size
56
```

So using a `staticmethod` object saves you 8 bytes (on Mac OS X, on another OS the byte count could differ slightly), but you don't usually *keep* a bound method (you'd use `instance.method()`, which creates the method object then discards it again after calling).

So, unless you are *storing a large number of bound methods*, this is not going to make enough difference to justify making your code unreadable by passing in the instance manually everywhere.

---

<sup>*</sup> Note that as of Python 3.7, for common cases Python doesn't even create method objects anymore. See the [*Optimisations* section of the 3.7 What's New notes](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.7.html#optimizations):

> Method calls are now up to 20% faster due to the bytecode changes which avoid creating bound method instances.

This applies to `<expr>.attribute_name(...)` call sequences, so an attribute name lookup followed directly by a call, in the same overall expression, provided only positional arguments are used. Special bytecodes are generated that validate that `attribute_name` resolves to a method name on the class, then calls the underlying function directly with the result of `<expr>` prepended. Python uses [`LOAD_METHOD`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_METHOD) followed by [`CALL_METHOD`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_METHOD) opcodes instead of [`LOAD_ATTR`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_ATTR) and [`CALL_FUNCTION`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION) opcodes, but falls back to the behaviour of the latter two if the optimisation doesn't apply.

Comment: But as far as I tried, bound methods were created for each instance, isn't that extra memory for each instance?

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL: I address that *in my answer*: _used only during the duration of the call or if you stored the bound method_. If you are not storing bound methods for every instance, there is no memory used, method objects generally exist only briefly. In modern Python releases, for the common cases, Python *doesn't even create the object*.